# How to re-arrange this formula to make "Y" the subject

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$p =\left(\frac{Y+K}{(Y/p_1)+(K/p_2)}\right)$$

Transpose this formula to make Y the subject

The answer is

$$Y = \left(\frac{Kp_1(p_2-p)}{p_2(p-p_2)}\right)$$

I have been unable to reach this, my answer is

$$Y = K\left(\frac{1-(p/p_2)}{(p/p_1)-1)}\right)$$

Comment: wow that formatting did not work at all...

Comment: just put the latex between '$'

Comment: it's done now lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

taking from where you left

$Y = K\left(\frac{1-(p/p2)}{(p/p1)-1)}\right)$

$1-(p/p2) = 1 - \frac{p1}{p2} = \frac{p2 - p1}{p2}$

similarly

$(p/p1) - 1 = \frac{p}{p1}-1 = \frac{p-p1}{p1}$

$Y = K\left(\frac{\frac{(p2-p)}{p2}}{\frac{p-p1}{p1}}\right)$

Now we know that

$\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{c}{d}} = \frac{ad}{bc}$

so

$Y = K\left(\frac{p1(p2-p)}{p2(p-p1)}\right)$

$Y = \left(\frac{Kp1(p2-p)}{p2(p-p1)}\right)$

SO this is the correct answer. The answer you are mentioning has incorrect denominator.

Comment: ahhh this makes sense now, can you just explain how you got my last step to the second line in yours?

Comment: Edited the answer. Still have the doubt??

Comment: Not any more. I'm a bit rusty on all this been doing random questions here and there. cheers mate

Comment: how tos upvote?

Comment: Dont bother about that .. when you got to know how to upvote then only do that. Dont hurry dont worry. Just keep doing what you do.